# How to set communicate spring with server in RestController

Tags: java, spring, server

From the client to the server is sended json, which have the value - the page number that is required to be imaging for user in client side, page by page:

```
19 17 * * * curl -d '{"explorerId":'1', "pageNumber":'1',"turnOff":true}' -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST http://localhost:8080/types
```

I have method, which get to client large list of entities. In method I split him (using pageNumber value and question to database) and want return to client page by page.

```
@RestController
public class WPRestController extends GeneralController {
    private final int COUNT_VALUE = 50;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/types")
    public Page typeprocess(@RequestBody PostTemplate postTemplate) {
        long pageNumber = postTemplate.getPageId() - 1;
        List<Words> wordsList = getWordsListOffset(postTemplate.getExplorerId(), pageNumber, COUNT_VALUE);
        int[] count = new int[]{1};
        String result = wordsList.stream()
            .map(p -> (count[0]++) + " " + p.toString())
            .collect(Collectors.joining("\n"));
        Page page = new Page();
        page.setNumber(pageNumber++);
        page.setContent(result);
        return result;
        }
    }
```

How to make is so, that user on client side, pressed key and resend query to server? 
i.e. - client must to get the content, also get pageNumber value and resend him in curl query automatically.

It is possible?